# Как исправить ошибки на сайте Wordpress который хостится на Namecheap EasyWP Supersonic?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, хостинг

Есть [сайт](https://pablo.partners/) который хостится на Namecheap EasyWP Supersonic

Сайт там медленно работает и внизу под футером отображаются ошибки, которые тормозят сайт
Скрыть или исправить их не удалось
Проверял работоспособность сайта на других хостингах там все работает быстро и без ошибок

```
Deprecated: Return type of WPNCEasyWP\WPBones\Database\WordPressOption::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/easywp-plugin/wp-nc-easywp/vendor/wpbones/wpbones/src/Database/WordPressOption.php on line 183
```

Deprecated: Return type of WPNCEasyWP\WPBones\Database\WordPressOption::offsetGet($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/easywp-plugin/wp-nc-easywp/vendor/wpbones/wpbones/src/Database/WordPressOption.php on line 193

Deprecated: Return type of WPNCEasyWP\WPBones\Database\WordPressOption::offsetSet($offset, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/easywp-plugin/wp-nc-easywp/vendor/wpbones/wpbones/src/Database/WordPressOption.php on line 178

Deprecated: Return type of WPNCEasyWP\WPBones\Database\WordPressOption::offsetUnset($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/easywp-plugin/wp-nc-easywp/vendor/wpbones/wpbones/src/Database/WordPressOption.php on line 188

Обращался в тех поддержку, уже месяц не могут дать ответа с чем это связано и также не могут это исправить.

Может у кого то были подобные ошибки?
Как их можно исправить?

По всей видимости ошибки возникают из за роботы плагина который используется на этом хостинге для оптимизации роботы WordPress

Отключить этот плагин или редактировать исходные файлы нет возможности, хостинг это запрещает

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: уже обращался, но без результатов, были ответы от разных типа ЭКСПЕРТОВ тех поддержи что проблема в самом сайте, при каждом обращеии я получал разный ответ который отличался от предыдущих

Comment: @orso связано это с тем, что в версии PHP 8.0 были изменены правила для интерфейсов `ArrayAccess` и других встроенных интерфейсов, требующие объявления типов возвращаемых значений для методов. Самостоятельно исправить Вы это не будете в состоянии, так как ошибка относится к некоему предустановленному плагину, и его нужно или обновить или деактивировать или понизить версию PHP.

Comment: @orso ну и предупреждения типа `deprecated` никак не влияют на скорость работы сайта и его работоспособность, потому причину медленной работы нужно искать в другом месте.

Comment: @orso пардон, в [PHP 8.1](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/internal-method-return-types)

Comment: @Simon спасибо. Есть тестовые хостинги на Hostinger и GoDaddy там сайт работает в разы быстрее, так что явно это связано с плагином WPNCEasyWP. Если исправить это нет возможности, скорей всего прийдется переносить сайт в другое место